# Conspiracy Theories and Epistemology?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, virtue-ethics, popper, social-epistemology

Is it prima facie irrational (Karl Popper’s view) or consistent with vice epistemological traits (Quassim’s view) such as gullibility to believe in conspiracy theories?

See new episode of Spotify/Apple Podcast, Oppinionated: Current of Philosophy. New Ad is on Leiter Report

Thank you for your comments. Sometimes, I forget my sophisticated philosophical audience, so let me be clear. I’ve read your comments. Allow me to put my original question into better context. This is not a promotion. I earn $0 from the podcast and in fact, losing lots of money, because I love philosophy and genuinely want to hear your opinions on this subject. I have a JD/MA in Philosophy and wrote a thesis in the social epistemology of testimony. If you’ve studied philosophy and have attended an APA, believe me, I have probably had a few drinks with your favorite philosopher.

Karl Popper is one of the top philosophers of science and argues that conspiracy theories are a pseudoscience and the people who believe in them are irrational. He believes that conspiracy theorists are people who believe in a society controlled by other people. His argument is a bit of a straw-man so many philosophers disregard it, but there is a better argument to discount conspiracy theoriey by Quassim Cassam, who argues that conspiracy theorists ought to be dismissed due to their faulty cognitive epistemic practices such as gullibility. Doubt me if you want. Please read the papers and answer the question. Cheers!

Popper, K.R. (1966). The Open Society and Its Enemies, vol. 2: The High Tide of Prophecy, 5th edition, Routledge and Kegan Paul.

Quassim Cassam, Vice Epistemology http://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/82006/2/WRAP_159.full.pdf

Comment: What does your second section mean? - Please give a reference that Popper utters the view from your first section. Thanks.

Comment: Second section seems to be a personal promotion...

Comment: Welcome to philosophy stack exchange!  See the FAQ for site policies.  That is found in the ? symbol at the top of the page.  This is not a well formed question, as the details of what you are asking about , and any prior research you have done, are presumably in your podcast, not in the question here.  See how to write a good question:  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask  Your question is likely to be closed due to being unclear.